# Landscape table in multicol-environment

Tags: floats, positioning, multicol, landscape

I am facing a very weird problem; see the output: [image: Output]

I am trying to get my table in the landscape mode within a two-column layout. Therefor the package "multicol" is used. The table does not appear on the whole page but ratheronly the top (or left, depending on the perspective). Whenever I remove the multicol package, the table does fill the whole page; but unfortunately the layout of the rest of the paper is destroyed. Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance. :)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\linespread{1.08} 
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape,multirow,rotating,caption,tabularx,booktabs}
[...]
\begin{document}
[...]
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}[b]
\small
\label{tab:2}
\caption{bla}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXXXX}
\hline & Grow Bed & DWC & NFT & Soil \\ \hline
[...]
Nutrient uptake  
&- High &- High& - Lower because smaller root-water contact area& - Lower
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table*} 
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It will be easier for others to help if you strip your example down to the bare necessities required to illustrate the problem. Why not just use the class option `twocolumn` instead of the `multicol` package?

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate the problem you describe. When I compile your code, I get a table in landscape taking the whole page.

Answer (score 4):

The landscape mode is not possible inside the `multicols` environment. Use `\rotatebox` instead:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\linespread{1.08} 
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lscape,multirow,rotating,caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\rotatebox{90}{%
\small
\minipage{0.9\textheight}
\captionof{table}{bla}\label{tab:2}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXXXX}\hline 
& Grow Bed & DWC & NFT & Soil \\ \hline
Nutrient uptake  
&- High &- High& - Lower because smaller root-water contact area& - Lower\\ \hline
Nutrient uptake  
&- High &- High& - Lower because smaller root-water contact area& - Lower\\ \hline
Nutrient uptake  
&- High &- High& - Lower because smaller root-water contact area& - Lower\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\endminipage}

\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Sorry, is there `e^x` function in PSTricks? `Euler^x` seems to be unusual. (It will be deleted shortly)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Found another workaround: \end{multicols} before inserting the table and \begin{multicols}{2} right after. :)